# "Pre-fetching" entities

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to optimize performance of my app in some areas, and one thing I was thinking about was 'pre-fetching' entities where there's a high probability I will be using them later in response to a user's query such that they will be in memcache for faster retrieval.

I was thinking about doing something like this (pseudo-code, basically):

```
def get(self):
    scored_documents = index.search(user_query)
    ndb_keys = get_keys_from_documents(scored_documents)
    ndb_keys_url_safe = [key.urlsafe for key in ndb_keys]
    taskqueue.add(queue_name='ndb_fetcher',
            url='/tasks/ndb_fetcher',
            params={'entity_keys':ndb_keys_url_safe})
    context = {
        # context data goes here
    }
    self.response.out.write(template.render(context))
```

The `ndb_fetcher` would basically just do a `ndb.get_multi()` call in a fast task queue. I don't want to do this prior to generating a response to the user because the entities are large and calls can take ~1+ sec. Also I don't need the data from ndb until a user requests it manually. So the hope is that a lot of the needed data from entities will already be in memcache so AJAX calls for information will be quicker.

Is this a reasonable way to approach the problem I'm stating?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you say.... you want to pre-fetch, but only AFTER the user called for the data?

what you seem to do with ndb is correct and will put everything in memcache.  But to pre-fetch... I don't really know

Comment: "Pre-fetch" is probably a bad term to use -- wasn't sure what else to say.

Comment: then what did you mean?  I'm trying to understand what you're doing but I'm a bit stumped as to your requirement.  If you need this query to run faster for "often run queries", maybe running a couple of ndb queries at the start of your app to just to put data in memcache could be done?

Comment: what about moving to AJAX? So you would render the page to the client, then make the request for the data via JS on the client side then populate the page with the data, when it arrives? Or if the user has to indicate they want to see it, just make it visible (if it's already arrived at that point)?